# JS Google Picker on file upload change file name

Tags: javascript, google-api, google-picker

I have created a google file picker and the user can either select an existing file or upload a new one.

I have got it working where the user can select or upload a file. However I want to define the filename myself if a user wishes to upload a file.

This is what I currently have:

```
function createPicker() {
    if (pickerApiLoaded && oauthToken) {
        let picker = new google.picker.PickerBuilder().
            enableFeature(google.picker.Feature.SUPPORT_TEAM_DRIVES).
            addView(new google.picker.DocsView().
                setEnableTeamDrives(true).
                setIncludeFolders(true).
                setParent("FOLDER-ID")
            ).
            addView(new google.picker.DocsUploadView().
                setParent("FOLDER-ID")
            ).
            setOAuthToken(oauthToken).
            setDeveloperKey(developerKey).
            setCallback(pickerCallback).
            hideTitleBar().
            build();
        picker.setVisible(true);
    }
}

// A simple callback implementation.
function pickerCallback(data) {
    let id = 'nothing';
    if (data[google.picker.Response.ACTION] === google.picker.Action.PICKED) {
        let doc = data[google.picker.Response.DOCUMENTS][0];
        id = doc[google.picker.Document.ID];
        console.log(doc);
    }

    let message = 'You picked: ' + id;
    document.getElementById('result').innerHTML = message;
}
```

I have had a look at the documentation [here](https://developers.google.com/picker/docs/reference#DocsUploadView) but I can't see anything there.

I don't know if this is even possible.

Comment: Maybe you can check the sample code in [this post](https://ctrlq.org/code/20393-google-file-picker-example)? Also could you check if [this github post](https://github.com/filestack/filestack-js) is helpful?

Comment: The sample code is useful but just does a normal example. The other github post is interesting but not what I'm after.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead I had to update the name manually if the user decided the upload a file.

```
// A simple callback implementation.
function pickerCallback(data) {
    console.log("Data", data);

    let doc = 'nothing';
    if (data.action === "picked") {
        doc = data.docs[0];

        console.log("Doc", doc);
    }

    let message = `You picked: ${doc.id}`;
    document.getElementById('result').innerHTML = message;

    if (data.viewToken[0] === "upload") {
        updateName(doc, "888");
    }
}

// Update the name of the file
function updateName(doc, newName) {
    newName += "." + doc.name.split(".")[1];

    let load = "https://content.googleapis.com/discovery/v1/apis/drive/v3/rest";
    gapi.client.load(load)
        .then(function () {
            return gapi.client.drive.files.update({
                "fileId": doc.id,
                "supportsTeamDrives": "true",
                "resource": {
                    "name": newName
                }
            })
                .then(function(response) {
                    // Handle the results here (response.result has the parsed body).
                        console.log("Response", response);
                    },
                    function(err) {
                        console.error("Execute error", err);
                    }
                );
            });
    }
```