# Angular Google Picker how to interrupt upload

Tags: angular, spring-boot, google-drive-api

I am currently working on an Encryption Web tool which should upload an encrypted file to Google drive.

Currently, I use uppy to send my file to my Backend encrypted it there and then upload the encrypted file to google Drive.

It is also working that I can download the decrypted file by using the Google Picker.
My Problem now the Google Picker also has an Upload view where I could upload files directly to the drive, but I want to send the file to my own Backend to encrypted it there.
Sadly I didn't find any other Component or code example how I could create a Google Drive Picker with an Upload function like I want.

I found this example ([JS Google Picker on file upload change file name](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49554448/js-google-picker-on-file-upload-change-file-name)) but there they manually change the uploaded file and i don't want that because then the file would exist for a short time not encrypted in my google drive.

Greetings :)